# typescript Angular2 Instantiating Injectable such as Http outside the constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a class that uses a private Http object and should be encapsulated.
I do not want my class to be Injectable.

If my class has a constructor such as:
constructor(private _http: Http) {}
then the caller must provide the Http object.

Looking at the examples in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html I could not find how to create an Http object outside the constructor.

What is the solution for such a request?

Thanks.

Comment: Best practice say you should always use DI so that you can better unit test you angular2 code and mock http for for  unit test . So not sure why you want to do this .

Comment: Yashveer Singh, Understanding that Injectables are singletons, maybe they (should) have a static method that returns a reference to the instantiated object?

Comment: Yashveer Singh, Can you reference me to an article about http mockup please?

Comment: I used mock for http in one of my poc project which and the source code is in Git https://github.com/yashveersingh83/ControlSubmissionClient/blob/master/src/app/recepient/recepient.service.spec.ts . This recepient.service.spec.ts uses mocking of http with a static service . Also check recepient.component.spec.ts where I unit test component with mocked service . If you need some help I am happy please let me know . Although I am new to angular2 but I think the git url provided above can help you a lot if you are learning angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually create an Http object to achieve your goal. The caller can obtain the Http object through dependency injection and pass it to your special class. This does not violate the conditions that you have mentioned.

On a side note you can create an Http instance manually by supplying an appropriate ConnectionBackend and RequestOptions.